# forms authentication is returning the logon page as html on unauthorized access?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

In my ASP.Net MVC app, if the user is logged out or Session times out during an ajax call the log-on page is being returned to the calling javascript ajax call as html. This causes an error on the client because it cannot parse the html.

I wanted to override the `handleunauthorizedrequest` on the `authorize` attribute but even after overriding it, this will not be hit while debugging and still the log-on page is returned.

My goal is to return an **401** status code if the request is an ajax request and if the request is unauthorized.

What is the solution to this problem, I still cant understand why the `handleunauthorizedrequest` does not get hit, isn't it overridden?

Comment: Have you applied the newly created custom authorize attribute on the controlers/actions?

Comment: yes, but it still does not override the base class. the overridden method is useless, is this because im using forms authentication?

Comment: can you post some codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the jqXhr object in jquery ajax has a state property which is accessible like so:

```
 jqXhr.state()
```

if the value of the state property is "rejected" then it means that a json result wasnt returned and your call was rejected.

I used the value of this property to determine if the session had timed out and I was able to redirect to the login page gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

The following should work.

```
public class CustomAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;
        if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            response.StatusCode = 401;
            filterContext.Result = new EmptyResult();
        }
        else
        {
            base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use the filter in controller or action as

```
//instead of Authorize
[CustomAuthorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And in the client side add a hook to the `ajaxError` event and check for the status code `401`.

```
$(function(){
    $(document).ajaxError(function (e, xhr, opts) {
        if (401 == xhr.status) {
            //do whatever you like
            //return document.location = document.location;
        }
    });
});
```

hope this helps.

Comment: My question was that the protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest does not get overridden and does not get hit.

Comment: Aside `from System.Web.Mvc` namespace, there is another `AuthorizeAttribute` class under `System.Web.Http` namespace. Which one are you working with?

Comment: System.Web.Mvc, what is the difference?

Comment: Not 100% sure, need to learn, but i think they work the same, but needs to put in appropriate context. `System.Web.Mvc` version for `Controller`, and `System.Web.Http` for `ApiController`. But then again i am not fully sure about that.

Answer (score 0):

The Default AuthorizeAttribute does not take care of AjaxRequest. You need to write your own implementation. I have given a sample implementation below, you can customize as required.

I have added an action in homecontroller to return a JsonResult and applied default [Authorize] attribute.

```
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult SayHello()
    {
        object result=new {status="200",res="Hello"};
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

In the view i have added a simple ajax event to invoke the action and display res as alert.

```
    <h3>
    <a id="anchorSayHello">Say Hello</a>
</h3>
@section Scripts{
    <script>
        $('#anchorSayHello').click(function () {
            $.ajax('/Home/SayHello', {
                success: function(data) {
                    var str = data.res;
                    alert(str);
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    </script>

}
```

As, you have told it will return an html response as unauthorize.

[image]

Now, lets implement custom Authorize attribtue and apply to the action

```
 public class TestAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            object res = new { status = "404", redirect = "/Account/Login" };
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult() { Data = res, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };

            return;
        }
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Now lets modify the Javascript as,

```
$('#anchorSayHello').click(function () {
            $.ajax('/Home/SayHello', {
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data.status === '200') {
                        var str = data.res;
                        alert(str);
                    } else {
                        window.location = data.redirect;
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
```

Now it should work as expected, for ajax request also it will redirect to login page.

[image]

Comment: as I said in the question, the problem is that the overriden method HandleUnauthorizedRequest does not get hit as if it is not overriden.

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET 4.5 the correct answer is to set [`HttpResponse[Base].SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.suppressformsauthenticationredirect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to true:

```
if (!httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated)
{
    if (httpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
    {
        httpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
    }
    return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
}
```